# Changing directories in go routines

Tags: go

I am trying to change directories in a go routine to directory x. I now want to use a different go routine that changes the directory to directory y. Will the execution of my first go routine be affected by this change to the current working directory in the second go routine? The purpose of wanting to do this is to introduce parallelism while doing similar tasks. If it does end up changing the CWD, what should be an alternative approach (forking...)?

Comment: The working directory is a property of the process. There's no way for a goroutine to change directories.

Comment: It's even slightly worse than that: it's a property of the *thread* on unix systems, and since goroutines can be run on multiple different threads you can find the CWD changed out from under you if your goroutine gets moved.

Comment: That's what I thought, so the only option then, would be to fork, I presume?

Comment: You can't fork a Go process. The only way to sanely manage this is to use absolute paths, or possibly chdir one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Evan has identified a fundamental flaw in attempting to use the 'change working directory' (CWD) system call.

I believe that @Evan is correct, and that the CWD is a *thread* property on some OS's.

As @Evan pointed out, a goroutine could be resheduled (for example at a function call, channel access, or system call) onto a different thread.

The implications are, it may be **impossible** to change the CWD (if Chdir() could change the threads CWD) because Go's runtime chooses to reschedule the goroutine on a different thread; its CWD could change invisibly and unpredictably.

Edit: I would *not* expect Chdir() to do anything other than change the CWD for the process. However, the documentation for the package has no mention of 'process'.

Worse, the runtime may change how things work with releases.

Even worse, it would be very hard to debug. It may be a 'Heisenberg problem', where any attempt to debug it (for example by calling a function, which the runtime may use as a reschedule point) may actually changes the behaviour in an unpredictable way.

Keep track of absolute path names. This is explicit, clear, and would even work across goroutines without any need for synchronisation. Hence it is simpler, and easier to test and debug.

Comment: FYI, Go provides `os.Chdir`, which is implemented for any platforms which can supported changing the process working directory. If it's there, using it is not problem.

Comment: @JimB - I've had a look at the documentation, and their appears to be no guarantee about how Chdir() will be implemented. I can strongly agree that changing only the processes current working directory, and not the threads current working directory is a good/sane choice. However that choice is not made explicit, which would make me nervous about using it, especially if one wanted to rely on it across releases and platforms.

Comment: I think my concern is valid, and *not* addressed by Go's os package documentation. That may be simply an oversight by the package documenters. However it is *not defined*, could be implemented in several ways, and without explicit documentation could change across platforms and releases. So a downvote seems unhelpful to me. Sorry to whine, but without evidence that it is incorrect, in which case I would delete the answer as unhelpful, I think it is a valid concern.

Comment: There is no guarantee about *how* most things are implemented, and the documentation doesn't have to say when things *aren't* broken. If os.Chdir doesn't work in some case, then it needs to be documented as such. If you have a test case that demonstrates the problem, feel free to file an issue.

Comment: BTW, posix threads guarantee that all threads share the same current directory, and the directory is a process attribute in the kernel. If and when this isn't the case in some new environment, os.Chdir and syscall.Chdir won't be there.

Comment: @JimB - AFAICT, the specific behaviour of Chdir() is undefined. I am willing to raise an issue about the lack of specificity in the documentation, and get this flushed out, as it seems to me unhelpful to be that vague. Further, it would seem on the face of it difficult to create a test case if my platform only implements change-processes-working-directory. Its implementing Chdir() that way doesn't provide any proof for other OS's or future releases. If you have some deeper insight than the documentation, please share.

Comment: os.Chdir *is* well defined, and it's implemented in a way that's compatible with supporting multiple OS's and architectures. If an OS doesn't support it, just like the many other system specific syscalls, it simply won't be implemented (or it will return an error).

Answer (score 5):

Like mentioned in the comments, keeping track of the current working directory in each goroutine will cause problems.

Try using [filepath.Abs](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Abs) to capture the absolute directory and store that instead. Then each goroutine can operate on it's own directory without worrying about it being "switched" under the hood. Just be sure you're not modifying the same file accidentally by multiple goroutines.

Edit: Removing a chunk of text per @Evan's comment. Use absolute paths :p

Comment: As per my comment, you can't depend on the CWD staying the same between one line and the next, because your goroutine could be rescheduled at any time on a different thread with a different working directory. So there is no way I know of in Go to do anything reliable with the CWD at all.

Comment: @Evan: That's not correct. Go provides `os.Chdir` which is implemented if the OS supports it (and I believe all supported OSs do). You can use it if it's there.